# iBatis invoking a Stored Procedure with Oracle Type as parameters

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, ibatis

I am using iBatis to converse with my application.  Here's the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE typ_object 
AS
  OBJECT
  (
     name    varchar2(10),
     address varchar2(100),
     tel_no  number
  );

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE
(
    in_oracle_type    typ_object
)
as
  l_date    date;
begin
    null;
    // Do something with object
end;
```

I need to invoke this from my Java class using iBatis.  I find no information online as to how to achieve this.

```
<procedure id="invokeSP" parameterMap="someInputMap">
  {call TEST_PROCEDURE (?)}
</procedure>

<parameterMap id="someInputMap">
  // Some code goes here - What?
</parameterMap>
```